# Altair conditional coloring of points

Tags: python, altair

### Problem

I am trying to simply color by two numerical conditions.  I can get the chart to work with one condition.  However, my inexperience with conditioning in Python and JavaScript leaves me wondering what I am doing wrong when I add two conditions.

### Import packages and load data

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
```

```py
mpg = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/byuidatascience/data4python4ds/raw/master/data-raw/mpg/mpg.csv")
```

I want this subset of data to be colored red

```py
mpg[mpg.displ.gt(5) & mpg.hwy.gt(20)]
```

### First color one condition chart that works

```py
(base.
  encode(x = 'displ',
         y = 'hwy',
         color = alt.condition((datum.displ > 5), 
                                alt.ColorValue('red'), 
                                alt.ColorValue('black'))).
  mark_point()
)
```

### Second plot with two conditions doesn't color according to the condition

```py
(base.
  encode(x = 'displ',
         y = 'hwy',
         color = alt.condition((datum.displ > 5) & (datum.mpg > 20), 
                                alt.ColorValue('red'), 
                                alt.ColorValue('black'))).
  mark_point()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well...

there is not an `mpg` variable in my data frame. Mapping to the correct column fixes my issue.  I wish an error reported.

```py
(base.
  encode(x = 'displ',
         y = 'hwy',
         color = alt.condition((datum.displ > 5) & (datum.hwy > 20), 
                                alt.ColorValue('red'), 
                                alt.ColorValue('black'))).
  mark_point()
)
```